# Functional equation on unit square

Tags: inequality, functional-equations

Suppose $F$ is a continuous function defined on the unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ satisfying the following properties :

i) $ F(a,a)=0,$ for all $a\in[0,1],$

ii) $F(a,b)=-F(b,a)$ for all $(a,b)\in[0,1]\times[0,1],$

iii) $F(a,b)\geq0$ if $a\geq b$.

Then does $F(a,b)>0$ imply that $a>b$?

**Edit 1.** Suppose $F$ is differentiable on the interior of the unit square. Would this change the answer to the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is true, and you don't need continuity or differentiability. Prove by contraposition:

**Claim:** If $a\le b$ then $F(a,b)\le0$.

**Proof:** If $a\le b$ then $b\ge a$ so $F(b,a)\ge0$ by (iii). But $F(b,a)=-F(a,b)$ by (ii). Substituting, we get $-F(a,b)\ge0$, i.e., $F(a,b)\le0$.

Comment: Well that is essentially one the properties. I'd like to see whether we get something stronger meaning the $\textit{strict}$ inequality.

Comment: @BigM Easy: If it were true that $a=b$, then by i) you get $F(a,b) = 0$, which is not the case. By contradiction, we have $a \neq b$. Combine with the previous explanation and you get $a > b$.

Comment: @BigM What I proved is the *same* as the strict inequality you're hoping to be true. It's not a restatement of property (iii).